# Render flash while using setRoot or push in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using wix/react-native-navigation I am having white flickering screen while using setRoot or push methods in navigation.
I tried setting     waitForRender: true , but it docent help .
snippet I tried dosen't work.

animations: {
      setRoot: {
        waitForRender: true
      }
    }

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem on RNN 7.7.0, what helped me is setting the default options

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
  animations: {
    push: {
      waitForRender: true,
    },
    pop: {
      waitForRender: true,
    },
    setStackRoot: {
      waitForRender: true,
    },
    showModal: {
      waitForRender: true,
    },
    dismissModal: {
      waitForRender: true,
    },
  },
})
```